# importing csv file in rstudio from hdfs using sparkR

Tags: r, csv, hadoop, hdfs, sparkr

i have stored .csv file on Hadoop HDFS,

```
hadoop dfs -ls /afs
DEPRECATED: Use of this script to execute hdfs command is deprecated.
Instead use the hdfs command for it.

17/01/12 15:15:49 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 1 item
-rw-r--r--   2 hduser supergroup  203572404 2017-01-10 12:04 /afs/Accounts.csv
```

i want to import this file to rstudio using SparkR.

i tried following command:

```
sc<-sparkR.session(master = "spark://MasterNode:7077",appName = "SparkR",sparkHome = "/opt/spark")
sContext<- sparkRSQL.init(sc)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

df<- read.df(sContext, "hdfs://MasterNode:54310/afs/Accounts.csv")
```

following error occurred:

```
> df<- read.df(sContext, "hdfs://MasterNode:54310/afs/Accounts.csv")
Error in handleErrors(returnStatus, conn) : 
  No status is returned. Java SparkR backend might have failed.
In addition: Warning message:
In writeBin(requestMessage, conn) : problem writing to connection
```

please help me to import Accounts.csv file into rstudio using SparkR.

Comment: why not just use https://github.com/RevolutionAnalytics/rhdfs ?

Comment: i have installed rhdfs. but want to import csv using sparkR. i mean i want to use R-spark functions to import csv file from hdfs. can you suggest any spark function that can be used to import csv file from hdfs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `fread` function of the `data.table` library to read from HDFS. You'd have to specify the path of the `hdfs` executable in your system. For instance, assuming that the path to hdfs is `/usr/bin/hdfs`, you can try something like this:

```
your_table <- fread("/usr/bin/hdfs dfs -text /afs/Accounts.csv")
```

If your "Accounts.csv" is a directory, you can use a wildcard as well `/afs/Accounts.csv/*` You can also specify the column classes. For instance:

```
your_table <- fread("/usr/bin/hdfs dfs -text /afs/Accounts.csv", fill = TRUE, header = TRUE, 
colClasses = c("numeric", "character", ...))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but can you tell me if i use `fread` can i process this data with sparkR functions or is there any other procedure to process data frame using sparkR

Comment: With `fread` you are able to load your csv from HDFS into R, so that you can operate with them just like any other R object. If you just want to process your data with SparkR, you have to use other functions that allow you to perform data operations without loading them in your R session. And it really depends on the kind of things you want to do.

Comment: Sparklyr (http://spark.rstudio.com/) is a nice package that also allows you to do this kind of operations (apart from SparkR)